# Getting data from Firebase offline database (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which is checking only one value is exist or not when get to second page and build ui according to this info, if I do that with regular way it takes time and getting an null error for a sec before page build also I have to read database too oftenly than I want, so is there any way to check data from only offline database while connected to internet?

Edit:

As summary, I have a HomePage and it shows whole list belongs to user recorded as favorite with a ListView.Builder and user only see and able to remove them from this screen, the only way to add anything to list is added from my second page, and I check the item added or not while building, if it's added my favorite button shape change and it remove when onpressed if it's not same button save it to favorite. You can check below codes(related parts)

HomePage:

```
class MyFirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyFirstPage({Key key, this.auth, this.userId, this.logoutCallback, this.user})
      : super(key: key);

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final VoidCallback logoutCallback;
  final String userId;
  final FirebaseUser user;

  static String routeName = "/MyFirstPage";

  @override
  _MyFirstPageState createState() => new _MyFirstPageState();
}

class _MyFirstPageState extends State<MyFirstPage> {
  String userId;
  List<Movies> _moviesList;
  Query _moviesQuery;

  final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  StreamSubscription<Event> _onMoviesAddedSubscription;
  StreamSubscription<Event> _onMoviesChangedSubscription;
  AuthStatus authStatus;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     _moviesList = new List();
    _moviesQuery = _database
        .reference()
        .child("movies")
        .orderByChild("userId")
        .equalTo(widget.userId);
    _onMoviesAddedSubscription = _moviesQuery.onChildAdded.listen(onEntryAdded);
    _onMoviesChangedSubscription =
        _moviesQuery.onChildChanged.listen(onEntryChanged);
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        if (user != null) {
          userId = user?.uid;
        }
        authStatus =
        user?.uid == null ? AuthStatus.NOT_LOGGED_IN : AuthStatus.LOGGED_IN;
      });
    });

  }


  void dispose() {
    _onMoviesAddedSubscription.cancel();
    _onMoviesChangedSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  onEntryChanged(Event event) {
    var oldEntry = _moviesList.singleWhere((entry) {
      return entry.key == event.snapshot.key;
    });

    setState(() {
      _moviesList[_moviesList.indexOf(oldEntry)] =
          Movies.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot);
    });
  }

  onEntryAdded(Event event) {
    setState(() {
      _moviesList.add(Movies.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot));
    });
  }

  signOut() async {
    try {
      await widget.auth.signOut();
      widget.logoutCallback();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  updateMovies(Movies movies) {
    //Toggle completed
    movies.watched = !movies.watched;
    if (movies != null) {
      _database.reference().child("movies").set(movies.toJson());
    }
  }

  deleteMovies(String moviesId, int index) {
    _database.reference().child("movies").child(moviesId).remove().then((_) {
      print("Delete $moviesId successful");
      setState(() {
        _moviesList.removeAt(index);
      });
    });
  }

...
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: _moviesList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {...}
```

SecondPage:

```
class MovieDetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  MovieDetailPage({Key key, this.title, this.auth, this.userId, this.user})
      : super(key: key);

  final BaseAuth auth;
  final String userId;
  final FirebaseUser user;
  static String routeName = "/MovieDetailPage";
  final String title;

  @override
  _MovieDetailPageState createState() => _MovieDetailPageState();}

class _MovieDetailPageState extends State<MovieDetailPage> {
  final GlobalKey<InnerDrawerState> _innerDrawerKey = GlobalKey<InnerDrawerState>();
  final GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState> _refreshIndicatorKey =
  new GlobalKey<RefreshIndicatorState>();

  Future<void> recorded(String idname) async{
    final dbRef = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
        "movies").orderByChild("unique").equalTo(idname).once();
    return dbRef;
  }
  String userId;
  final FirebaseDatabase _database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  List<Movies> _moviesList;
  AuthStatus authStatus;


  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>
          getNamePreferences().then(updateName));
    });
    _moviesList = new List();
    widget.auth.getCurrentUser().then((user) {
      if (user != null) {
        userId = user?.uid;
      }});

  }

//I have a FutureBuilder for getting details

FutureBuilder<Payload>(
          future:  getData(_name),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done && firstRun == true)
              return Center(child: Image.asset("images/dice.gif"));
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done)
              if (snapshot.hasError)
              {....

// and I have a second FutureBuilder for my FAB because its change according to data
                  floatingActionButton:  FutureBuilder(
                          future: recorded(userId+snapshot.data.imdbId),
                          builder: (context, snapshots) {
                            return Container(
                              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  FloatingActionButton(
                                      heroTag: 3,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.4),
                                      onPressed: ()
                                      {
                                        Movies movies = new Movies(snapshot.data.imdbId, snapshot.data.originalTitle, snapshot.data.posterPath, snapshot.data.backdropPath, snapshot.data.releaseDate, snapshot.data.title, snapshot.data.voteAverage, snapshot.data.genres, false, userId, userId+snapshot.data.imdbId);
                                        snapshots.data.value == null ?
                                        _database.reference().child("movies").push().set(movies.toJson())
                                            :
                                        FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
                                            .child('movies')
                                            .orderByChild('unique')
                                            .equalTo(userId+snapshot.data.imdbId)
                                            .once()
                                            .then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                          Map<dynamic, dynamic> children = snapshot.value;
                                          children.forEach((key, value) {
                                            FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()
                                                .child('movies')
                                                .child(key)
                                                .remove();
                                          });
                                        });
                                        setState(() {});
                                      },
                                      child: Icon(snapshots.data.value != null ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border )
                                  )

                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                      ),
```

Comment: Can we see your current approach? They are many ways to await for Future response. Give us more details

Comment: I added more information and code samples to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`goOffline` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/goOffline.html), which forces the Firebase client to disconnect fro. the server. After calling that method, it'll try to fulfill read operations from its local cache (either in memory or on disk), and keep a queue of pending write operations to send to the server when it reconnects (either when the app restarts, or when you call `goOnline`).

By default the Firebase client keeps an in-memory cache of all data it has seen. You can [enable disk persistence](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/FirebaseDatabase/setPersistenceEnabled.html), which makes it then also write that cache to disk, so that it can reuse if when the app is restarted while you're offline.

Comment: I added "FirebaseDatabase.instance.setPersistenceEnabled(true);" to my main dart and offline() to initstate of second page and online() to initstate of first page, that helps a lot to make less reads but still I get a momentary null error when I go to second page. Any way to ignore or press this momentary null error, I alreday have functions for null scenario, I was using sqlite type floor database before and that never happens, maybe I can use both and make them sync when app start which ı have any  clue how yet.

Comment: I handled error side with "if (snapshots.hasData)" so it works as I want thanks.